# PyQt4 - Applying a stylesheet on an object which inherits from QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, stylesheet, qwidget

I am having an issue with PyQt4. I have a class which inherits from QWidget. This class uses a layout to store a QLabel and a QLineEdit. Here is the code:

```
class SearchBar(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(SEARCHBAR_STYLE)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setMargin(0)
        layout.addStrut(SEARCHAR_HEIGHT)

        lbl_notification = QtGui.QLabel('Hi')
        lbl_notification.setStyleSheet(SEARCHBAR_NOTIFICATION_STYLE)
        layout.addSpacing(10)
        layout.addWidget(lbl_notification)

        searchbox = QLineEdit('Search')
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(searchbox)
        layout.addSpacing(10)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

and here is the stylesheet:

```
SEARCHBAR_STYLE = """
                  QWidget {
                      background: #424a7d;
                  }
                  .QWidget {
                      border: 1px solid grey;
                  }
                  QLabel {
                      border-top: 1px solid grey;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
                  }
                  """
```

Now, my problem is that the stylesheet does not apply the way I would like it to. It only applies on my QLabel when the border should be around the whole object:

[image]

When I had a function creating my search bar as a QWidget, it worked perfectly, but now that I changed that to a class it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

EDIT 2: The previous code, before I change it to a class, was this:

```
def create_bar():
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.setSpacing(0)
    layout.setMargin(0)
    layout.addStrut(SEARCHAR_HEIGHT)

    lbl_notification = QtGui.QLabel('Hi')
    lbl_notification.setStyleSheet(SEARCHBAR_NOTIFICATION_STYLE)
    layout.addSpacing(10)
    layout.addWidget(lbl_notification)

    search_bar = QtGui.QLineEdit('Search')
    search_bar.setMinimumSize(200, 25)
    search_bar.setMaximumSize(200, 25)
    search_bar.setStyleSheet(SEARCHBOX_STYLE)

    layout.addStretch()
    layout.addWidget(search_bar)
    layout.addSpacing(10)

    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    widget.setStyleSheet(SEARCHBAR_STYLE)
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    return widget
```

Comment: what is `SearchBox`?

Comment: When you say the following: **changed that to a class**, what do you mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc SearchBox is a class which inherits QLineEdit and has some override functions in order to suit my needs. I left it out of the question because I dont think it is relevant to my problem

Comment: @eyllanesc I used to call a function which returned a QWidget, which was basically a container for my SearchBar. I applied my stylesheet to this container - just how I am now applying the stylesheet to self - and it worked fine.

Comment: I do not understand your specific question, explain better, what you get, and what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry for the confusion, I want the previous result, which is this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/y8iFvCC.png). As you can see, the border covers the whole QWidget

Comment: You could give a minimal example of the code that works for you and which code will fail you, if SearchBox is irrelevant, change it to QLineEdit.

Comment: @eyllanesc I just edited in the old code that used to work

Comment: Please change SearchBox by QLineEdit to avoid confusion. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc just did

Comment: With your previous code or the new one I get what you want, maybe I'm implementing your code wrong, so I do not have that problem, you could share your code from both cases through github, drive, dropbox or similar and thus be able to fully test the problem.

Comment: I will give it another try and see if it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Surely you have already found your mistake. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the base class of SearchBar from QWidget to QFrame, or alternatively implement a [style sheet aware paintEvent](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget):

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    opt = QStyleOption()
    opt.initFrom(self)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)
```

Then change the style sheet to

```
SEARCHBAR_STYLE = """
SearchBar {
    background: #424a7d;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
"""
```